# PHP Associative Array Specific Value.

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now. Please any advice would be appreciated. I just need to access the array for ["Item"]. How do I gain access to this?

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Name"]=>
      string(10) "AuthorList"
      ["Type"]=>
      string(4) "List"
    }
    ["Item"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Smith, Joe"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "Peter, Ann"
      [2]=>
      string(18) "Magoo, Mr"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information, than what looks like a var_dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this structure is in a variable called `var1`, you should be able to access `Item` using:

```
$var1[0]->Item // returns the array
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. I was really complicating things. After too many hours of working on this project, my mind has gone to mud.

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain it.

Like you see, your first array index is an object.
If you see something like this in your var_dump than you can access it through deferencing the object.

It's the same like you would create an object and would like to access a public variable:

```
$var1 = new Object();
// when your Object variables are public so you could access them by deference the Object

echo $var1->myVariable; // will echo the public variable "myVariable"
```

So the answer from adam is the right one :)